# Reformat data to plot a calibration curve using geom_errorbar() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

**Intro:**

I have a dataframe of summary statistics for three different air quality measurements. The instrument names are `aa34`, `aa35`, and `48c`. They each measure carbon monoxide in ppm. I have the data in wide format, where each vector is the mean, standard deviation, standard error, or 95% confidence interval for each of the three instruments.

I would like to plot these summary statistics using `ggplot()` and `geom_errorbar()`, but I am having some trouble getting the data into long format and providing an ID variable for the color mapping in `ggplot()`. I am following [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/) tutorial. Below is the figure I would like to reproduce (replacing the guinea pig teeth data with noxious fumes of course). I'm stuck trying to add an additional y variable and have them be color coordinated by an `ID` variable. My desired output would replace the `supp` vector from the example with two of the three `id` vectors, namely the ones that contain `aa34` and `aa35`. My equivalent to the `dose` vector would be `ref.co.mean`, our `x` variable. My equivalent to the `len` vector would be the vectors `aa34.co.mean` and `aa35.co.mean` in long format.

[image: link]

**The Data:**

```
## Here's what my data frame looks like. 
## I know it's ugly, but if you copy and paste it into your console it should work!
df_cal <- structure(list(ref.co.mean = c(1.23638284617457, 1.46466241535712, 
2.16020882959014, 2.55054760052641, 3.13141175081258, 3.86968879644661, 
6.5914211520901), ref.co.sd = c(0.0196205483139859, 0.0229279198586359, 
0.0172965018302434, 0.0164690175286326, 0.00583116470707786, 
0.00975072766851073, 0.0388826652553337), ref.co.se = c(0.00346845569085442, 
0.00193776290206006, 0.00166435666462165, 0.00127061228762621, 
0.000583116470707786, 0.00229826855196908, 0.00614788918523735
), ref.co.ci = c(0.00707396201972773, 0.00383130164529687, 
0.00329939297398704, 
0.0025085329371034, 0.00115702958592763, 0.00484892279298878,  
0.0124352796323718), id = c("48c", "48c", "48c", "48c", "48c", 
"48c", "48c"), aa34.co.mean = c(0, 0.248857142857143, 0.823777777777778, 
1.256, 1.886, 2.446, 4.54), aa34.co.sd = c(0, 0.0716567783084826, 
0.0660714166547489, 0.0777970497665622, 0.0518459255872629, 0, 
0.0690217357069497), aa34.co.se = c(0, 0.00605610310675521, 
0.0063577250318932, 0.00600217269807407, 0.00518459255872628, 0, 
0.0109132946446067), aa34.co.ci = c(0, 0.0119739921598931, 
0.0126034483753748, 0.0118499152368743, 0.0102873564420935, 0, 
0.0220742219853317), id = c("aa34", "aa34", "aa34", "aa34", "aa34", "aa34", 
"aa34"), aa35.co.mean = c(0.2915625, 0.801035714285714, 1.39911111111111, 
1.80436904761905, 2.45672, 3.02355555555556, 5.134975), aa35.co.sd = 
c(0.0691998633940125, 0.0474980316455754, 0.0846624379229758, 
0.0822798331713915, 0.0595577165445419, 
0.0178768075145867, 0.0243007072942329), aa35.co.se = c(0.0122329231657723, 
0.00401431635364878, 0.00814664688751334, 0.00634802694633388, 
0.00595577165445419, 0.00421360393984362, 0.00384227919014218), aa35.co.ci = 
c(0.0249492112853266, 0.00793701687349159, 0.0161497773125, 
0.0125327252345785, 0.0118175430765459, 0.00888992723110191, 
0.00777174323014678), id = c("aa35", "aa35", "aa35", "aa35", 
"aa35", "aa35", "aa35")), .Names = c("ref.co.mean", "ref.co.sd", 
"ref.co.se", "ref.co.ci", "id", "aa34.co.mean", "aa34.co.sd", 
"aa34.co.se", "aa34.co.ci", "id", "aa35.co.mean", "aa35.co.sd", 
"aa35.co.se", "aa35.co.ci", "id"), row.names = c(1L, 33L, 173L, 
281L, 449L, 549L, 567L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Here's my first attempt:**

```
## This code only gets half of the job done...
## 95% Confidence Intervals for Error Bars:
p <- ggplot(df_cal, aes(x=ref.co.mean, y=aa34.co.mean)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=aa34.co.mean-aa34.co.ci, 
                      ymax=aa34.co.mean+aa34.co.ci), width =.05) +
    xlab("Reference CO (ppm)") + 
    ylab("AA34 CO (ppm)") + 
    geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x, se = FALSE) + 
    geom_point(size=2, shape = 21, fill="White") + 
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color, linetype=2, color = "firebrick") + 
    ggtitle("CO Calibration @ 0% RH") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    annotate("rect", xmin = 4.80, xmax = 5.70, ymin = 0.70, ymax = 1.70, 
       fill="white", colour="red") +
    annotate("text", x=5.25, y=1.50, label= "R^2 == 0.994", parse=T) + 
    annotate("text", x=5.25, y=1.20, label= "alpha == -0.9490", parse=T) + 
    annotate("text", x=5.25, y=0.90, label= "beta == 0.849", parse=T)
p
```

[image: link]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `dput(df_cal)` to make this easily reproducible?

Comment: Further, I am wondering where you calculated your summary statistics? Was it `Excel`? This could be made much easier using the `SummarySE` function from the `Rmisc` package as in your example link.

Comment: @ J.Con Thanks for the `dput()` tip. It's not pretty, but it seems to work if you copy and paste into the console. I am still using `R` to calculate my summary statistics. I am manually filtering out the "plateaus" from a 7-step time series using `dplyr`. I am then using some basic functions to generate vectors of the standard deviation, standard error, and 95% confidence intervals for each of the three instruments at each of the 7 steps. I then do a `row_bind()` on each of the 7 calibration steps, followed by a `unique()` which provides only one observation per calibration step.

Comment: Here's the [7-step time series](http://imgur.com/MO02Y3H) I used to generate those summary statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with switching to long format here is that you then have a variable of **length 7** for the x axis and 2 variables of combined **length 14** for the y axis. Therefore, this solution binds the rows so that the reference (x axis) data is included twice. It is then a matter of using `colour` and `group` in the `ggplot` aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)

df_aa34_2<-df_cal[,c(1:4,6:10)]#select first 'aa' group including reference data (48c)
df_aa35_2<-df_cal[,c(1:4,11:15)]#select second 'aa' group including reference data (48c)
names(df_aa34_2)<-names(df_aa35_2)#colnames must be the same for rbind function
DF<-rbind(df_aa34_2,df_aa35_2)#bind rows

p <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=ref.co.mean,y=aa35.co.mean,colour=id,group=id)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=aa35.co.mean-aa35.co.ci, 
                    ymax=aa35.co.mean+aa35.co.ci), width =.5) +
  xlab("Reference CO (ppm)") + 
  ylab("AA34 & 35 CO (ppm)") + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x, se = FALSE) + 
  geom_point(size=2, shape = 21, fill="White") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color, linetype=2, color = "firebrick") + 
  ggtitle("CO Calibration @ 0% RH") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 4.80, xmax = 5.70, ymin = 0.70, ymax = 1.70, 
           fill="white", colour="red") +
  annotate("text", x=5.25, y=1.50, label= "R^2 == 0.994", parse=T) + 
  annotate("text", x=5.25, y=1.20, label= "alpha == -0.9490", parse=T) + 
  annotate("text", x=5.25, y=0.90, label= "beta == 0.849", parse=T)+
  theme_bw() 
p
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thanks! I liked your use of `rbind()` instead of trying to use `reshape2` or `tidyr`. I've been pairing the `melt()` function with `left_join()` to get the data in a similar format, but your version involves fewer lines of code. Now to include some additional `annotate()` lines to include the second `lm()` output.